# Headless browser using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried to use (jp@gc - HtmlUnit Driver Config) to create a headless browser test using jmeter, but I get this error

Response message: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "getComputedStyle" is not defined.

I read online and it suggest that jp@gc - HtmlUnit Driver Config doesn't support javascript. Is there a way I can fix this via jmeter? or is there any other option to do headless browser testing. I have linux server as load injector

Update:

I have a webdriver sampler to open google page

> WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
>   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

and have downloaded Phanton JS, but when I run it it doesn't show anything on the report. Should I add any other config?

[image]

Comment: I have removed single quotes from value for phanton in the image above.

Comment: Looking at logs I see the errors java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)

Answer (score 1):

**HtmlUnit** do not support very well JS.

I done many tests and used each one and i can say that **PHANTOMJS** is the best one with good support of all JS/CSS... have a beautiful renderer to have nice screenshots.
by code you can use it like this (you can download it from here http://phantomjs.org/download.html (phantomjs-1.9.8 is very stable)):

```
Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  
                ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
                        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                        "your custom path\\phantomjs.exe"
                    );
 WebDriver   driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

If you want to do that via JMeter GUI, you need to add  before your `Logic Controller` an element `JSR223 Sampler` [JSR223_Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
and inside the script panel :

```
org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities caps = new org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities();
        ((org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        ((org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        ((org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
                org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                "your custom path\\phantomjs.exe");
        org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = new org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getCurrentSampler().getThreadContext()
                .getVariables().putObject(com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.BROWSER, driver);
```

Do not hesitate if you need more informations.

Comment: I found that there is a new plugin to do that https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/

Comment: i think it's a plugin or libs problem, can you try my proposition with JSR223 Sampler